# firebase/init.js does not contain appId

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-hosting

I am using this to initialize the Firebase app:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

To my surprise this file is missing the `appId` entry. When I look at the config for the project it is there (see https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592).

Why is `appId` missing in "init.js"? How do I add it?

Comment: The linked documentation doesn't say anything about an entry called appId.  I don't have it either, and everything works fine.  Is there something specific that doesn't work for you?  If so please edit the question to say what it is that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson The documentation does not say anything, but following the instructions under "Get config object for your web app" shows a config object with "appId". (Otherwise it is the same values as in "init.js". I am trying to implement FCM in my app. `appId` seems to be required there.

Comment: Is something with FCM not working the way you expect?  If you can show that there is a specific problem, with an error message or some other unexpected behavior, then you could file a bug report with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson It is not working at all yet. I am trying to find out what I have missed. And then I stumbled upon this little problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson Just if someone is reading I need to clarify. I saw some posts on the net about trouble with FCM and appId. I did not read carefully so maybe they did not say that appId is needed for FCM. Anyway, I have test `firebase.initializeApp` both with and without `appId`. Both works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect you didn't follow all the setup instructions completely.  Be sure to go back and follow them all, especially [part 2: Register your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#register-app) where you create an app in the console to associate your web app with its configuration.

If you've followed all the instructions exactly, please [contact Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly for troubleshooting assistance.

Comment: Thanks, that might sometimes be the case. I never read very carefully because I expect the people providing the services are logical enough to protect me. But I think I have registered the app correctly. I will contact support about the missing appId.

Comment: Looking closer at this I can see that there are two bugs (or more) involved. The (from my point of view) simple one is that the `appId` does not show up in "init.js". The second (more difficult one) is that the PWA cache is not always updated the way I understand it should be updated.

Comment: You have to deploy to hosting in order for the `__/firebase/init.js{on}` files to get updated with the appId. It appears like they are statically served from hosting (which makes sense) and are generated when a new version is deployed to hosting but not when an app is associated with an existint hosting site.

Comment: This is actually still not resolved. What I see now is that the project somehow seems to have two "apps". One of them have tell me to use init.js. The other instead shows what I supposed was in init.js and tells me to add this myself. The init.js loaded by the usual link does not include appId.